# How do I solve $\int_D\int\ln(1+x^2+y^2)dxdy$, where D : $x^2+y^2\leq9, x\geq0,y\geq0$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I recently had a calculus exam and one of the questions for it was as below. I know how to solve for normal double integrals generally speaking, but I'm not too certain of what I had to do here. It seems to be a double integral problem over general regions, but it doesn't seem to fit particularly. It's really the Ln part that gives me pause and makes me not sure of what to do past it. If someone could show how to solve this problem, I would appreciate it immensely!

$\iint\limits_D\ln(1+x^2+y^2)dxdy$, where D : $x^2+y^2\leq9, x\geq0,y\geq0$.

Comment: The way you would type that is you would use \iint\limits_D

Comment: Since the region is a (part of a) disc and there is a $x^2+y^2$ in the $\ln$, maybe use polar coordinates?

Comment: For double integrals use \iint_D ($\iint_D$)

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\limits_{0}^{3}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}ln(1+x^2+y^2)dxdy = \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int\limits_{0}^{3}r\ln(1+r^2)drd\phi=\frac{\pi}{4}(10\ln 10 -9)$$
using substitution $t=1+r^2$ in last integral.